# How to redirect to Google map if installed, otherwise redirect to Appstore for install Google Map using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I need to open google map in my iOS App. If google map is installed, navigate to google map, otherwise redirect to AppStore for install Google Maps. This is my tries

```
 if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {

            print("app found")
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=9.9894,76.5790&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(lattitude),\(longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }else {

            showAlertWithTitle(title: "App not found", message: "You need to install Google Map", fromViewController: self)
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
     }
```

Comment: please add your code or tries

Comment: @SagarChauhan I can navigate to google map if installed. Need to navigate AppStore to install Google Map if its not installed

Comment: @SPatel Added my code. Kindly pls check

Comment: Did you added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist ? see this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `UIApplication openURL` with a URL that starts with `http://maps.google.com`.

If the user has the Google Maps app installed, the app will be launched.

If the user doesn't have the app installed, Safari will be opened to the Google maps page. Besides showing the map, that page will give the user the option to go to the App Store to get the app if desired.

This approach has the most flexibility and offers the user the greatest choice of what they want to do.

An alternative is to use the approach you stared and check for the `comgooglemaps` scheme. In your `else`, you can display a `SKStoreProductViewController` passing in the app id for the Google Maps app (585027354).

Comment: I like the idea. Thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {

            print("app found")
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }else {

            UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-transit-food/id585027354?mt=8")! as URL)
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
        }
```

Also please add below code in your info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Please add code and let me know, Above code will open google map if installed in your device otherwise it will redirect to app store.